# Sub claim is missing

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Using IdentityServer4 and Windows authentication all seems to be well but when calling SignInAsync it throws with a missing sub claim error. I've done various approaches but always the same error.  In the below screenshot you can see the "sub" is being added so why does it say it's missing?

Startup.cs

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Controller

```
var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

if (result.Principal is WindowsPrincipal principalUser) {...all fine here}

context.SignInAsync(...);//**BOOM**
```

[image: IdSrv4]

Comment: isn't here the solution: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1758 ?

Comment: Sounds like the wrong authentication scheme is used. What did you set as default authentication scheme? Please read the first paragraph of the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x _Specifying the default scheme results in the HttpContext.User property being set to that identity. If that behavior isn't desired, disable it by invoking the parameterless form of AddAuthentication_

Comment: Updated question

Comment: You have to remove 'HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme' from 'AddAuthentication()' to make possible using CookieAuthenticationScheme as a default one. Then you manually set the scheme in ChallengeAsync() and AuthenticateAsync() and that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to call `services.AddAuthentication(HttpSys.DefaultsAuthenticationSchme)` before calling `services.AddIdentityServer`

Comment: ...so the idsrv built in configuration overrides yours. but what about keeping your initial order and just removing the default scheme override? guess that should work as well